# Problems with expanding parent from child height. Body will not 100% height. Multiple columns

Tags: css, html, height, overflow

Having real problem with a column layout and my css. I have tried all of the tricks but to now avail. Please have a look here. Code starts on line 419.

http://justpost.me/lcc/

Both "mainBody" and "sidebar" do not expand their parent (body).

Essentially the "body" is no expanding to 100% of viewport.

- Tried clearfix
- Tried overflow hidden
- Tried clear both divs
- Tried additional wrappers/ divs

Thanks for your help,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Almost answered my own question. I removed some of the additional code at the top of the stylesheet for the body. Now the body is expanding.

However, the "mainNav" doesn't size to height.

Have fixed to a nice standard with a fixed position.